# Is there any way to change override method parameter names from SDK in Android Studio?

Tags: android

I am often struggling often with parameter names from overridden methods' parameter names. So, when I work I always change them to understand myself better and make less mistakes.

I wonder how many bloggers have easy-to-understand names for those overridden methods' parameters, something like this:

Bloggers use like this:

[image]

But mine, it's just `viewGroup`, `i` for `onCreateViewHolder()`

My IDE is like this:

[image]

Not only this, Whenever I create listeners or fragments, I encounter those problems. I always change the parameter names like `p`, `i`, `i1`, `i2` into `pos`, `parent`, `index` or something like this.

is there any way to customize the parameter names?

Comment: Not sure if I understand correctly, but in Java you can just change the name of the parameter as you wish in an overridden method. Only the signature needs to remain the same.

Answer (score 1):

Name of variable does not matter and @override makes no difference here (it is just indication you intentionally override parent class method). So as long as your variable is of *right type* (in this case `ViewGroup`) you can name it as you like.

Comment: Yes, but when I use libraries from SDK, the parameter names are confusing. And I'd like to customize them. Is it impossible?

Comment: This makes non sense for me or I don't get it. Why does it even matter? If I make a library, with method `methodName(String someConfusingNameOfArgument)`, then what is your probelm with that? You need to invoke method named `methodName()` and pass String to it. Name of argument does not is irrelevant

Comment: That's because sometimes, it's difficult to understand what the parameter for. If I can rename it, I wouldn't be confused again or avoid mistakes. And if the parameter is just `i1` or `i2`, I need to check the document again, which can be wasting time. And I can't really memorize all the parameter names for each overridden method. And I was curious, how all the bloggers have different parameter names from mine and their parameters are easy-to-understand. And I thought there can be a way. @Marcin Orlowski